# PHP Sessions null in an ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I have a PHP page that sets some session values:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["key"] = "myvalue";
```

The value is set and if I open a new tab in the browser on my file, `sessions.php`, I see the value previously set.

```
<?php
    if(!session_id()) {    // check if we have session_start() called
        session_start(); 
        echo  "<br />session start"; 
    }

    if (!isset($_SESSION["key"]) ) {
        echo  "<br />session null"; 
    } else {
        echo "ok my session" . $_SESSION["key"] ; 
    }   
?>
```

If I open the same file from another page, in the same tab same domain same folder through AJAX I have null sessions.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",   
    url: "/php/sessions.php",
    cache: false,
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {}
}).done(function(msg) {
    alert(msg) // I get session null
});
```

**EDIT:**
I'm using php-5.6.10-nts-Win32-VC11-x64 with IIS

**EDIT2:**
I realized that the middle page that made the Ajax call was in the same domain. So this was qwhy Imy sessions were null

Comment: I don't see anything in there that sets `bcc` key in `$_SESSION`.

Comment: Which php version you are using?

Comment: @AjeetKumar What does PHP version have to do with this?

Comment: Is /php/sessions.php echoing $_SESSION["key"] some how?

Comment: Sorry @JonStirling bcc is only something I forgot to change.

Comment: @Ajeet Kumar I added the version

Answer (score -3):

You apparently forgot to echo

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["key"] = "myvalue";
echo $_SESSION["key"];
```

So your file has some output to ajax